# Taxi.js in Wordpress with Contact Form 7 o Woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am integrating [taxi.js](https://taxi.js.org/) with Wordpress to simulate navigation as a SPA, all is working but when I want to integrate with Contact Form 7 or Woocommerce the js functions it stopped working. In this page ([https://bryhel.com/](https://stackoverflow.com)) they are using taxijs with wordpress and the contact form 7 is working fine. But I dont know how the do that, I was doing some tests with data-taxi-reload in the scripts but nothing works, some ideas? thanks.

Ive tried adding the attribute data-taxi-reload to the scripts generated with wp_footer() with "script_loader_tag" hook Wordpress.

```
function ntdev_addModuleAttrAppjs($tag, $handle, $src){
            $tag = '<script src="' . $src . '" id="'. $handle .'-js" data-taxi-reload></script>';
        return $tag;
    }
    add_filter('script_loader_tag','ntdev_addModuleAttrAppjs', 100, 3);
```

but it doesnt work